# htaccess, Suphp and mod_rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, php, suphp

I bought a script called fastAmazon. The developer wrote it for traditional server config using mod_rewrite.

My hosting (site5) utilizes SuPHP which I've learned requires that the php config rules be out of htaccess and into the php.ini file. Okay simple enough, commented out php_flag and it finally loaded. The problem is that once I try to go to any other page I get a 500 error.
Something in this config isn't allowing the rewrite of other pages and I CANNOT figure it out!

The dev said it's probably something to do with the [L] line endings but won't help further on a SuPHP config...

```
#php_flag display_errors Off
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mypages/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /sitemap.php?target=google [L]
RewriteRule ^urllist.txt$ /sitemap.php?target=yahoo [L]
RewriteRule ^outgoing/(.*)$ /out.php?url=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ /page.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [QSA]
```

Comment: What urls work, and what urls don't? Is the .htaccess placed in the `/mypages` folder? Where does sitemap.php reside?